# sql sentence with wildcards and null values

Tags: java, sql, null, wildcard

i got 4 combo boxes with values and could also be wildcards '%'.
As you know the NULL values are not returned.

I used the (COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'VALUE' OR COLUMN_NAME IS NULL), it worked in some way but it's not what i need.
What i need would be to return also the NULL values for example in this case:

```
NAME = '%'
LASTNAME = '%'
ZIPCODE = '12345'
EMAIL = '%'
```

Basically, i want this to return all the ZIPCODE like '12345' and also the null values from the other 3 (NAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL).

Don't know if i'm being clear :(

If i'm not, let me know,

How can I achive this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dynamically create your sql based on the parameters that are needed

Comment: Your SQL part is not clear. Are you going to build customized queries (SQL statements) in your Java code or do you need "universal" query that can cover all your use cases?

Answer (score 2):

use LIKE operator in your SQL statements. According to your database, use NVL,ISNULL,IFNULL.

**Oracle;**
    NVL(NAME,' ') LIKE '%'
**MSSQL;**
    ISNULL(LASTNAME,' ') LIKE '%'
**MySQL;**
     IFNULL(EMAIL,' ') LIKE '%'

And use prepared statements. Do not build your SQL statements with merging string values. Prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care what the value is, and you don't care whether it's `null` or not, then don't even include the column in the where clause:

```
where zipcode = '12345'
```

Also, I'm guessing that your '%' values result from the user choosing not to search by that value.  I would represent that differently in your program, with perhaps a Java `null` or an empty string "", so that '%' could still mean something closer to what it means in a SQL "like" where clause fragment -- any value except `null`.

Comment: is that, im sorry is not actually java. Those are html (jsp spring) combo boxes. So when i click in a javascript function, that function sends to ESB all the values to a pre-built SQL query inside a flow.

Comment: No, of course, "where zipcode = '12345'" is not Java.  That's just how your where clause will look in SQL.

Comment: Yep, my SQL does something like the following
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 WHERE (COL1 LIKE #[json:VALUE1] OR COL1 = NULL) AND (COL2 LIKE #[json:VALUE2] OR COL2 = NULL) AND (COL3 LIKE #[json:VALUE3] OR COL3 = NULL) but this doesn't fit my needs even though it works. Happens that i care about the other null values.

Is like doing the following:
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COL1 LIKE VALUE1;
This will return all the rows where the col1 is like value1 and the null values from the other columns. That's what i want with the wildcard stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for -

```
    (lastname_col like :lastname or :lastname = '%' ) and 
    (zipcode_col like :zipcode or :zipcode = '%' ) and  
    and so on
```

The above sql should give you the result even when :zipCode is '12345' and the rest of the values are null.

Comment: Yeah i was saying to rgettman that this is my current query:
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 WHERE (COL1 LIKE #[json:VALUE1] OR COL1 = NULL) AND (COL2 LIKE #[json:VALUE2] OR COL2 = NULL) AND (COL3 LIKE #[json:VALUE3] OR COL3 = NULL)

But this, which is the same as your example, let's say all are wildcards except for zipcode which is 1234, this will return ALL the zipcodes that are 1234 and also the NULL ones. Well, that's what i don't want, don't return the null for the one you've searched.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, myy query is a bit different than yours. Yours is (COL1 LIKE #[json:VALUE1] OR COL1 = NULL). Mine is (COL1 LIKE #[json:VALUE1] OR #[json:VALUE1] = NULL). Do you see the diff ?

Comment: Yep but in my case #[json:VALUE] won't be null but '%'. :( so that case will never happen (in my situation)

(#[json:VALUE] is the value passed from the JSP in a json format to the ESB.)

Possible values = Strings or wildcard.

Comment: I've edited the answer, would that work ? Basically changed the condition to (COL1 LIKE #[json:VALUE1] OR #[json:VALUE1] = '%')

Comment: Didn't return any NULL values :(